# Sorting an array in foreach

Tags: php, arrays, magento, sorting, foreach

I am trying to sort an array inside foreach.
Following is my code:

```
<?php $_images = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages(); ?>
<?php $i = 0; foreach ($_images as $_image){ $i++; ?>
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(300,300); ?>" style="width:50px;height:50px;">
<?php } ?>
```

I need the images to be printed out in the correct order. It should be ordered by the value of:

```
$_image[position_default]
```

I have tried using Ksort:

```
<?php $_images = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages(); ?>
<?php $i = 0; foreach ($_images as $_image){ $i++; ?>
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(300,300); ?>" style="width:50px;height:50px;">
<?php ksort($_image['position']);  ?>
<?php } ?>
```

But it does not sort them at all. Maybe i don't use it correctly?
Any suggestions? :)

Some output of $_image:

```
[224] => Varien_Object Object
                (
                    [_data:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [value_id] => 224
                            [file] => /s/a/salty_fred_kn_kket.jpg
                            [label] => 
                            [position] => 2
                            [disabled] => 0
                            [label_default] => 
                            [position_default] => 2
                            [disabled_default] => 0
                            [url] => http://webshop.simplychocolate.dk/media/catalog/product/s/a/salty_fred_kn_kket.jpg
                            [id] => 224
                            [path] => /home/www/webshop.simplychocolate.dk/media/catalog/product/s/a/salty_fred_kn_kket.jpg
                        )

                    [_hasDataChanges:protected] => 
                    [_origData:protected] => 
                    [_idFieldName:protected] => 
                    [_isDeleted:protected] => 
                    [_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [247] => Varien_Object Object
                (
                    [_data:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [value_id] => 247
                            [file] => /i/m/image_150.jpg
                            [label] => 
                            [position] => 3
                            [disabled] => 0
                            [label_default] => 
                            [position_default] => 1
                            [disabled_default] => 0
                            [url] => http://webshop.simplychocolate.dk/media/catalog/product/i/m/image_150.jpg
                            [id] => 247
                            [path] => /home/www/webshop.simplychocolate.dk/media/catalog/product/i/m/image_150.jpg
                        )

                    [_hasDataChanges:protected] => 
                    [_origData:protected] => 
                    [_idFieldName:protected] => 
                    [_isDeleted:protected] => 
                    [_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [258] => Varien_Object Object
                (
                    [_data:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [value_id] => 258
                            [file] => /a/v/avatar.png
                            [label] => 
                            [position] => 3
                            [disabled] => 0
                            [label_default] => 
                            [position_default] => 3
                            [disabled_default] => 0
                            [url] => http://webshop.simplychocolate.dk/media/catalog/product/a/v/avatar.png
                            [id] => 258
                            [path] => /home/www/webshop.simplychocolate.dk/media/catalog/product/a/v/avatar.png
                        )

                    [_hasDataChanges:protected] => 
                    [_origData:protected] => 
                    [_idFieldName:protected] => 
                    [_isDeleted:protected] => 
                    [_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )
```

Comment: You need to sort your array before the `foreach` loop.

Comment: I can't tell if you want to sort by the `$_image['position']` key or the `$_images[key]` key?

Comment: $_image is going to be a single image. Sorting a single-element array is pointless. You need to ksort $_images, and since you're sorting a specific key, probably need to use uksort.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use a custom sorting function, because you will want to compare with the value of one of the "properties" of each image. (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)
So before the loop, put:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return strcasecmp($a['_data']['position_default'], $b['_data']['position_default']);
}

usort($_images, "cmp");
```

Edit: I changed from uksort to usort, made a mistake there.

Edit2: Given the output for $_images that you added, the `position-default` property is one level deeper, so I added the `['_data']`.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, it looks like the ksort should happen before the `foreach` loop.

```
<?php ksort($_images);  ?>
<?php $i = 0; foreach ($_images as $_image){ $i++; ?>
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(300,300); ?>" style="width:50px;height:50px;">
<?php } ?>
```

Give that a try. Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Do you think you could provide a set of the data (at least the structure) returned by the `Mage::getModel()` call?